# What's the difference between 'subdued' and 'moderate'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning

I cannot tell the difference between 'subdued' and 'moderate'.

I saw 2 sentences:

Experiment A produces subdued response.

Eperiment A produces moderate response.

Are there any difference? Could you explain about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

"Subdued" gives the idea of very little, restrained, or less than expected.

"Moderate" gives the idea of average, or something that is not large and not small.